# Como eu posso usar a função href="#"?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Eu estou a fazer um site, e eu queria fazer com que quando alguém clicá-se num botão não fosse para o inicio da página mas sim para o meio da página e, ou o final 
da página.

Explicando melhor[Link](http://prntscr.com/na1jqq)(Por favor vejam esse link), quando alguém clicá-se no "home" iam para a parte azul, que é o topo da página, e quando clicá-sem no "Acerca" fossem para a parte amarela.

Comment: Bom dia. Não se trata de uma função, mas de um atalho. Visite o site https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brasil. Ao posar o mouse sobre o índice história, tu verás no canto inferior esquerdo do teu computador o seguinte link https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brasil#Hist%C3%B3ria. Se tu clicares sobre ele, o scroll mover-se-á automaticamente até o índice solicitado. Só isso. Tu podes, claro, usar este tipo de marcação com eventos Javascript, mas daí é outro assunto. Para aprender Javascript acesse: https://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp

Answer (score 2):

`href="#pularpara"` e sua div com a id relacionada ao href `id="pularpara"`

```html
<a href="#pularpara">clique aqui para pular...</a>
<div style="height:5000px">Nada</div>
<h1 id="pularpara">Para Pular</h1>
```

Comment: eu posso fazer isto?   <h1> <id="About the game"> About the game</h1>

Comment: mudei o exemplo para de div para h1, vc nao pode usar dessa forma descrita.

Answer (score 1):

Usando âncoras:

```
<a href="#topo">Topo</a>
<a href="#meio">Meio</a>
<a href="#fim">Fim</a>

<div id="topo">Div Topo</div>
<div id="meio">Div Meio</div>
<div id="fim">Div Fim</div>
```

Observe que os `href` são respectivamente os `id` de cada `div`, sendo assim, quando clicar no `<a href="fim">` a pagina vai ser rolada até que a parte superior da `<div id="fim">` fique no topo da janela do navegador.

Answer (score 0):

Use âncoras para resolver esse problema, é bem simples.

```html
<a href="#div1">Link 1</a>
<a href="#div2">Link 2</a>

<div id="div1" style="width:200px;height:400px;background-color:red"></div>
<div id="div2" style="width:200px;height:400px;background-color:blue"></div>
```